# how to get the image information after attaching a picture in Access form like date and time of capture

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I would like to fetch image captured information ( Date & Time) after uploading image as attachment in access form. need assistance .

Comment: Store this data in a field at time of image capture.

Comment: thanks but i am looking when i upload picture as attachment  a text  should display with information that when picture has been taken

Comment: Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/datecreated-property. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: Thank you so much yes this works but instead date created is it possible to get for date Taken

Comment: If it's an attribute offered by Windows Explorer, then yes. Set Explorer for Details view and see what columns you can select for viewing. I do see one for DateTaken. Try that in the code.

Comment: i am not finding                                                                                                         
 Set f = FS.GetFile(Me.txt_laptopimg.Text)

'Debug.Print "              Size: " & f.Size
'Debug.Print "      Date Created: " & f.DateCreated
'Debug.Print "Date Last Accessed: " & f.DateLastAccessed
'Debug.Print "Date Last Modified: " & f.DateLastModified
'Debug.Print "              Type: " & f.Type
Me.lbl_laptopimagedate.Caption = f.DateCreated

Comment: I stand corrected. Just because Windows shows the property doesn't mean FSO has it.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work.

```
Sub GetDatePictureTaken(strFolder, strFileName)
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim objShell, objFolder
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strFolder)
    strDate = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.ParseName(strFileName), 12)
    strDate = CleanNonDisplayableCharacters(strDate)
    Debug.Print strDate
End Sub

Function CleanNonDisplayableCharacters(strInput)
Dim strTemp As String, strChar As String, i As Integer
      strTemp = ""
      For i = 1 To Len(strInput)
          strChar = Mid(strInput, i, 1)
          If Asc(strChar) < 126 And Not Asc(strChar) = 63 Then
              strTemp = strTemp & strChar
          End If
      Next
      CleanNonDisplayableCharacters = strTemp
End Function
```

Resources:
[Trying to use Shell object and FileSystemObject in VBScript for file manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252057/trying-to-use-shell-object-and-filesystemobject-in-vbscript-for-file-manipulatio)
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/3f220113-8b7c-4d32-9681-cdcc942e1f17/vbscript-systemphotodatetaken-problem